# Issue exporting crystal reports crosstab to excel?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have a crosstab that has a time field inside, it shows well formatted on crystal, but when I export it to excel, it shows 12:00 am in all the fields. Does someone know how to solve this? I am using CR 14.1.1.1036 and excel 2013. See sample below[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can format the cell so it hides the 12:00 AM in the field data.

[custom cell formatting](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/02/25/custom-cell-formatting-in-excel-few-tips-tricks/)

Answer (score 0):

From Code behind re-format you datatable cell, use something like:

```
 NDT = DT.Clone()
    Select Case rptid
         NDT.Columns(0).DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
                    For Each row As DataRow In DT.Rows
                    Dim dr As DataRow = NDT.NewRow
                    For i As Integer = 0 To NDT.Columns.Count - 1
                        dr(i) = row(i)
                        If i = 0 Then
                            If Not dr(i) Is DBNull.Value Then
                                dr(i) = Convert.ToDateTime(row(i)).ToShortDateString()
                            End If
                      Next
                    NDT.Rows.Add(dr)
                Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula to convert it in Crystal.  Excel will recognize it as a date when it pulls in there.

```
cstr({Table.field},'MM-dd-yyyy')
```